# ChartKick library hash doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using the chartkick gem with Rails 5.0.1. Looking around online, I see there is a 'library' hash where you can pass in values such that certain graph items change. (i.e. xAxis labels, tooltip text, etc.) I try to add the library hash and nothing happens different to the graph.

For example `= column_chart [["Item A", Value], ["Item B", Value]]` Will create a regular column chart, but there is no title.

So I try: `= column_chart [["Item A", Value], ["Item B", Value]], library: {title: "Graph"}`

The graph is rendered normally, but the title is not labeled as "Graph". This is just an example, however. Any other library option I have found online doesn't work. What am I missing to make this work?

**Edit: Somehow I solved it. Answer below.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I have made a mistake somewhere in my code that was conflicting with the javascript file from working. Honestly, I'm not quite sure what I did differently since I've been trying different things. As it stands I have    `//= require Chart.bundle` before `//= require chartkick` in my application.js file and i have Chart.bundle.js in my vendor/assets/javascripts folder. It seems this is all it took and all seems to be good now. I believe i may have had conflicting code somewhere and just missed that conflicting code while looking through what I had.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you see the `:library` hash? I see `:xTitle`, `:yTitle` and `:label` instead, but they are passed direct next to the data (not inside a hash).

```
<%= line_chart data, xtitle: "Time", ytitle: "Population" %>
```

Comment: doing a quick google search on chartkick renders a bunch of information and different ways of doing things with chartkick. Many of them make use of a 'library' hash, which seems to go hand in hand with highcharts or google charts. I've included these in the project but they don't seem to do anything.

Comment: I have looked at the source. That's why I came here. Couldn't figure out what I've missed. I've done everything that site says, I believe.

Comment: FYI, you can pass options directly to the charting library via a library hash, see the bottom of [this section of the readme](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#options).

Comment: Thanks BigRon i missed that earlier.